# How to divide an Aggregate and Sum function

Tags: tableau-api

I am working in Tableau and trying to create a formula that will return me the value of each customer that walks into a store by dividing Net Sales / Traffic. When I try to combine the two separate formulas, it gives me the following error: Cannot mix aggregate and non-aggregate arguments with this function. The two functions I created that I'm trying to divide are:

```
SOT = (SUM([Sales Net])-SUM([Sales Gcard Net]))/SUM([Traffic Perday]) and SOT Goal
```

When I look at it in Tableau, it's stating that SOT is an aggregate function. How do I work around this to be able to get

```
SOT / SOT Goal
```

Comment: Can you give a snapshot of your data and calculated fields used to calculate this ratio?

Comment: [SOT]/SUM([SOT Goal])? Or perhaps MIN SOT Goal may be more appropriate, depending on your data structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate variables are values that are calculated in the view, and depend on the level of aggregation in Tableau. e.g. sum(Sales) will show different values in Tableau if it’s next to a Region dimension, or if it’s next to a Category dimension.

In order to avoid the errors you can use many solutions.  My favorite is indeed LOD expressions.  In your view, though I do not have required sample data and therefore, I cannot try my hands on different possibilities here, I suggest that this should work-

```
SOT = ({SUM([Sales Net])}-{SUM([Sales Gcard Net])})/{SUM([Traffic Perday])}
```

**Do remember that this solution will over-ride your filters and if you are using filters you have to add all those to Context.**

**EDIT**

While trying different possibilities remember these things...

1. `{SUM([Sales])}` will sum the sales over *entire data* and {} i.e. curly braces wrapped around the sum function will cause to return the value as non-aggregate.  In other words, this will work as LOD and if you'll add this field to view, the sum of entire sales will be shown against each row.
2. `{FIXED [DIMENSION NAME] : sum([Sales])}` will sum sales separately for each Dimension value.  Fixed statement (LOD) again returns the value as non-aggregate value.  if you'll add this field to view, the sum of entire sales for that dimension will be shown against each dimension.

Comment: Thanks Anil, that did work however the same answer came up for all the values. I have to analyze the sales for many stores and they all currently have the same SOT. How would I be able to individualize?

Comment: When we wrap an aggregate expression in curly brackets we are actually using a LOD without fixed/include/exclude.  Now `fixed` lod also has same property i.e. it outputs the expression as if it is non aggregate but usage of right dimension with fixed will ensure that results are not same for each row.  Therefore if you want row-wise different results you have to use fixed argument inside {}.  If you are still unable, please provide a sample data, desired output, I'll suggest you.